# Display php array in js

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
   if(in_array($ext,$audioArr))
   { 
    $aud=$row['news_media'];
?>
    <div id="player2" class="aplayer"></div> 

    <script>
    var ap2 = new APlayer({
        element: document.getElementById('player2'),
        narrow: true,
        autoplay: false,
        showlrc: false,
        music: {
            title: 'Preparation',
            author: 'Hans Zimmer/Richard Harvey',
            url: 'media/<?php echo $row['news_media']; ?> ',
            pic: 'icons/2.jpg'
        }
    });
    ap2.init();  
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}?>
```

In my code, I have a loop that prints audio repeatedly. But i don't know how to print php variable  `echo $row['news_media']` in js .I want to print this at url: 'media/ ?> '. So plz help me. I tried many tricks from this site but i could not find the right one.

Comment: you miss ?> end syntax and use like this <?php echo $row["news_media"]; ?>

Comment: thanks for reply but my script is right. I gave ends properly

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed this :

```
    <?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
   if(in_array($ext,$audioArr))
   { 
    $aud=$row['news_media'];
    ?> // This close
    <div id="player2" class="aplayer"></div> 

    <script>
    var ap2 = new APlayer({
        element: document.getElementById('player2'),
        narrow: true,
        autoplay: false,
        showlrc: false,
        music: {
            title: 'Preparation',
            author: 'Hans Zimmer/Richard Harvey',
            url: 'media/<?php echo $row['news_media']; ?> ',
            pic: 'icons/2.jpg'
        }
    });
    ap2.init();  
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
url: 'media/<?php echo $row['news_media']; ?> ',
```

with

```
url: 'media/'+<?php echo $row['news_media']; ?>,
```

Hope this will help.

Enjoy!

You have issue in php close tag. Below is solution. Try it

```
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
   if(in_array($ext,$audioArr))
   { 
    $aud=$row['news_media'];
?>
    <div id="player2" class="aplayer"></div> 

    <script>
    var ap2 = new APlayer({
        element: document.getElementById('player2'),
        narrow: true,
        autoplay: false,
        showlrc: false,
        music: {
            title: 'Preparation',
            author: 'Hans Zimmer/Richard Harvey',
            url: 'media/'+<?php echo $row['news_media']; ?>,
            pic: 'icons/2.jpg'
        }
    });
    ap2.init();  
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it not works. Do you have anything else??

Comment: Try above script. Done some modification in php close tag.